# SQL: Add missing rows

Tags: sql, database, relational-database, hana

I want to add additional (missing) rows to a table.
Existing situation: I have a patient table where is a registration date and I calculate how long the patient is already registered in weeks ("TimeInProgram"). Now I aggregate over this to get the number of patients which are currently in this period (see COUNT -> attribute "Patients"). In the end I sum with a window function to get the number of patients who WERE already in a specific period.

```
SELECT aggregation.*, SUM("Patients") OVER () "All", SUM("Patients") OVER (ORDER BY "TimeInProgram" DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) "PatientsCounterInTime" FROM (
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "PatientID") "Patients", "TimeInProgram" FROM (
SELECT
    pat."PatientID",
    ROUND(((DAYS_BETWEEN(pat."RegisteredOnDate", NOW())+1)/7.0), 0, 'ROUND_UP') "TimeInProgram"
    FROM t_patient pat
    ORDER BY "PatientID"
) data
GROUP BY "TimeInProgram"
ORDER BY "TimeInProgram"
) aggregation
```

The result you can see here:

[image: (PatientsCounterInTime PLUS Patients of the following row is the value of PatientsCounterInTime of the following row.)]

PatientsCounterInTime PLUS Patients of the following row is the value of PatientsCounterInTime of the following row.You can see the problem: There are some "TimeInProgram"-weeks are missing like week 4 or week 5 because at the moment no patient is in this period. So I want to add the missing rows. The value of "PatientsCounterInTime" should be 162 in week 4, week 5. and "Patients" of course 0.

I use HANA as database.

Kind regards and thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

```
  SELECT "TiP" "TimeInProgram", "Patients", "PatientsCounterInTime" FROM (
        SELECT aggregation.*, SUM("Patients") OVER () "All", SUM("Patients") OVER (ORDER BY "TimeInProgram" DESC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) "PatientsCounterInTime" FROM (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "PatientID") "Patients", "TimeInProgram" FROM (
        SELECT
            pat."PatientID",
            ROUND(((DAYS_BETWEEN(pat."RegisteredOnDate", NOW())+1)/7.0), 0, 'ROUND_UP') "TimeInProgram"
            FROM "t_patient" pat
            ORDER BY "PatientID"
        ) data 
        GROUP BY "TimeInProgram"
        ORDER BY "TimeInProgram"
        ) aggregation
    )
    RIGHT JOIN "t_time_in_program" t ON "TimeInProgram" = t."TiP";
```

[image]

(PatientsCounterInTime PLUS Patients of the following row is the value of PatientsCounterInTime of the following row.)

Comment: You need a calendar table containing all weeks,essentially a single column with with 1 to 48 and LEFT JOIN on that

Comment: In addition to what Mihai said, you'll have to use LEAD or LAG to get the last partients counter time when joining(SINCE it will have a null value after left join)

Comment: Thank you for you helpful answers! I joined the table and updated the post above. I'm not sure how to use LEAD/LAG now to fill in the missings column's data. Any hint again? @sagi

Answer (score 0):

You can find time tables in the "_SYS_BI" schema.
In case there are none, [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-25977) is the helpful article

Here is the example how to use it. Let's say you want to display period from 2000 to current Year:

```
WITH dataset AS (
    Select '2016' as YEAR, '216' AS PATIENTS FROM DUMMY
    union all
    Select '2010' as YEAR, '200' AS PATIENTS FROM DUMMY 
)
SELECT 
        distinct tdim.year,
        case when dataset.PATIENTS is null then 0 else dataset.PATIENTS end  
    FROM "_SYS_BI"."M_TIME_DIMENSION_MONTH" tdim
left outer join  dataset on tdim.year = dataset.year
where tdim.year >=2000 and tdim.year <= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
```

Would be great, if you can send table create statements + some inserts for the data, so I might be ale to help you more.